# Проверка равнозначности условий выбора SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Допустим, имеются условия выбора от SQL запросов:

1). `field = 1 AND field3 in (1,2,3)`

2). `(field3 = 1 or field3 = 2 or field3 = 3) AND field = 1`

Есть ли стандартные средства, которые смогут мне сказать в данном случае, что условия идентичны?

Comment: Никакие стандартные средства вам не скажут, что эти условия идентичны. По той простой причине, что эти условия не идентичны.

Comment: Скосил на ночь глядя... 2). (field3 = 1 or field3 = 2 or field3 = 3) AND field = 1 . Вот там самом деле должно выглядеть второе условие-)

Comment: А причём ту C#? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Есть 2 сервера. Там есть таблица в которой содержаться условия, которые подставляются в запросы, которые динамически генерятся. Нужно проверить равнозначность этих условий в таблицах между 2 серверами. Как-то так коротко выглядет задача.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сложный, но надежный вариант - сравнить синтаксические деревья

- дописать к каждому выражению `select * from sometable where`. Отдать этот SQL классу [`TSql120Parser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsql120parser) из Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql.dll.
- в результирущем дереве найти `InPredicate`, заменить на несколько OR
- трансформировать `WhereClause` - раскрыть скобки - `C and (A or B) -> C and A or C and B`, `A AND (B AND C) -> A AND B AND C`
- отсортировать операнды OR. отсортировать операнды AND.
- сравнить два дерева

Простой но не слишком надежный вариант - сравнить два плана выполнения:

Выполнить оба выражения как

```
SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON
GO
select count (*) FROM Table_1 where 
(field3 = 1 or field3 = 2 or field3 = 3) AND field1 = 1 
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
GO
SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF
GO
```

записать оба результирующих xml, и сравнить их, исключая заведомо неравные куски (вроде `StatementText`). С большой вероятностю планы будут одинаковы - SQL Server разворачивает in в or и раскрывает скобки при выполнении.

Comment: 'трансформировать WhereClause - раскрыть скобки - C and (A or B) -> C and A or C and B, A AND (B AND C) -> A AND B AND C'                            С раскрытием скобок не возникнет проблем? Ведь возможно, что будет очень много разных скобок, неизвестной вложенности.                Мне нравится вариант с планом запросов, но есть пара моментов:  1) Планирофщик отсортирует выполнит сортировку параментров в условии? Ведь условия могут стоять на разных местах                      2)Нужно обращаться к таблицам, для которых предназначены эти запросы...

Comment: А не подскажете, как правильно воспользоваться парсером?                  Создал   TSql100Parser, скормил туда Скрипт и получил переменную типа TSqlScript, что дальше я с ней могу сделать? Документация по Parser'у на офф сайте не очень богата на примеры=(

Comment: 1. Планировщик сортирует параметры, по крайней мере у меня. Но все зависит от фазы луны. Проверяйте. 2. С 'SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON' реального выполнения не будет. запрос вернет одно значение - план. Из кода такое надо выполнять 3-мя раздельными запросами, без GO. 3. С парсером - смотрите результат в отладке - там здоровое дерево.

Comment: А в каком поле искать это дерево? Там есть несколько полей, которые похожи на дерево

Comment: @iluxa1810 примерно в `.Batches[0].Statements[0].QueryExpression.WhereClause.SearchCondition`

Comment: А то что находится в: .Batches[0].Statements[0].QueryExpression.WhereClause.SearchCondition является корнем? Соответсвенно FirstExpression правое поддерево, а SecondExpression левое?

Comment: А можно сделать сортировку, которая не трогает ключевые слова? Т.е к примеру я могу инициализировать массив через Split {"field1=10","and","field2=100500"}, применяю кастомную сортировку и поля меняются местами, не затрагивая ключевое слово and.

Comment: @iluxa1810 SearchCondition - корень. FirstExpression и SecondExpression скорее всего придется разбирать для каждого бинарного выражения (AND/OR). Насчет сортировки - это задача преобразования деревьев. Обычно решается рекурсивным обходом дерева. Т.е. вам нужно идти по дереву, сравнивать First/Second, и, по необходимости, менять их местами. Похожий механизм используется в LINQ - ExpressionVisitor. Посмотрите примеры работы с ним, если вам нужна идея для "сортировки" дерева.

Answer (score 1):

По какому критерию вы хотите их сравнить?

1. Можно сравнить по результату, который они возвращают:
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790753/comparing-two-large-sql-queries
   (стоит заметить, что могут быть случаи, когда результат совпадет сейчас, но не совпадет потом).
2. Можно сравнить время обработки.
3. Или вы хотите именно на логическом уровне их сравнить?

Comment: На логическом уровне

Comment: @iluxa1810, в добавление к ответу PashaPash - может вам еще поможет [explain](http://habrahabr.ru/post/211022/)?